# Using TransactionScope() with NHibernate's BeginTransaction() problem

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, transactionscope

I'm using NHibernate 3.1.0 with the MySql Connector 6.3.5. As a general rule my repository methods are wrapped in an NHibernate transaction. However the service or application code calling the repository methods might also require a transaction scope - therefore the mixing of NHibernate transactions with .NET's TransactionScope. A simulated test looks like this:

```
[Test]
public void CanPerformNestedSave()
{
    using (var tx = new TransactionScope())
    {
        var user = new AdminUser { Email = "user@test.com", Name = "Test User 1", Password = "123" };

        using (ISession session = OpenSession())
        {
            using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                entity.ModifiedAt = DateTime.Now;
                session.SaveOrUpdate(entity);
                tx.Commit();

                return entity;
            }
        }

        tx.Complete();
    }
}
```

The test fails with the following error:

*NHibernate.TransactionException : Begin failed with SQL exception
  ----> System.InvalidOperationException : Nested transactions are not supported.*

I've scoured the web to find a solution to this scenario and hopefully the community on StackOverflow can help.

Comment: Thanks to Lulian (below). In the end, I decided to rather implement my own Unit Of Work pattern, making use of the NHibernate session.BeginTransaction to manage it.

Answer (score 1):

I've blogged about this [here](http://www.erata.net/net/nservicebus-with-nhibernate-and-mysql/).

In the blog post NServiceBus creates the outer TransactionScope for the handlers and the Nhibernate session and transactions are used inside the handler.

Comment: Thanks Lulian, I have read your article but since I'm not using NServiceBus, I'm struggling to understand the article's relevance to my problem. I have two different methods of initiating transactions - one from NH and the other from .NET - and although they should play well together, they don't seem to. I just get a _Nested transactions are not supported_ error.

Comment: In the case of NServiceBus there is the same problem since it always executed the handlers in a TransactionScope context. And inside the handler you need to use a NH transaction. So basically you have an outer TransactionScope and an inner ITransaction and MysqlConnector does not support this out of the box.

Comment: Just to clarify, the article suggests to modify the mysql connector. You can find the details of the change in the comments